# backbone collection: _.after isnt called after async requests

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to update a collection of posts individually and after each request has finished then re-render my collection.

Currently the code below never triggers renderPosts and I have no idea why

```
onClickCopyPosts: function(posts, publish_target) {

        var self = this;

        var renderPosts = _.after(posts.length, function() {
            console.log('got here');
            self.collection.fetch({reset: true});
        });

        _.each(posts, function(post) {
            post = new PostModel(post);
            post.set('id', null);
            post.set('publish_target', publish_target);
            post.save({success: renderPosts});
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature of save is `model.save([attrs], [options])`  .. And `success` handler is an option here.

So when you define the signature as `post.save({success: renderPosts});` the success handler is passed into the attributes which does not perform any action.

Change it to

`post.save({}, {success: renderPosts});`

**or**

`post.save(null, {success: renderPosts});`

Passing the option as the second parameter.